# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm working on a react project and trying to display a dialog with react-bootstrap. I just copied a working react-bootstrap snippet in a js file but it's not working for me, I'm having `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` next to the `<div className='static-modal'>` line.

Here is the content of the js file:

```
(function (context) {

  // notification view
  TheGraph.Notification = React.createFactory( React.createClass({
  //TheGraph.Notification = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
    },

    handleHide: function () {
      alert('Close me!');
    },

    render: function () {
      return (
        <div className='static-modal'>
          <Modal title='Modal title' bsStyle='primary' backdrop={false} animation={false} container={mountNode} onRequestHide={handleHide}>
            <div className='modal-body'>
              One fine body...
            </div>
            <div className='modal-footer'>
              <Button>Close</Button>
              <Button bsStyle='primary'>Save changes</Button>
            </div>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
})(this);
```

When I put use " in return line as follows:

```
return ("<div className='static-modal'><Modal title='Modal title' bsStyle='primary' backdrop={false} animation={false} container={mountNode} onRequestHide={handleHide}><div className='modal-body'>One fine body...</div><div className='modal-footer'><Button>Close</Button><Button bsStyle='primary'>Save changes</Button></div></Modal></div>");
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactCompositeComponent.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object
```

Any idea what is the mistake here?

Comment: Are you precompiling the JSX syntax into JavaScript or using the browser transpiler?

Comment: no i'm not, I just tried similar snippet that worked on fiddle (without the `createFactory`)

Comment: It's not valid unless it's precompilng somewhere. A quoted string doesn't compile into JSX. https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html

Comment: ok so I have to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile this file an instead of using directly I would rather use the output of babel

Comment: Babel or the JSX compiler from Facebook should work.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are using inside `render` is JSX , browsers as of now doesn't understand jsx . So we need `transpilers` to convert them to pure JavaScript .

You need to have a build process that `transpiles` your jsx code into javascript and then you should load that `transpiled` js in your HTML.

But if you just quickly want to play with react without setting up the build process , you can go [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and do that manually every time and paste that inside `render`

```
React.createElement(
  'div',
  { className: 'static-modal' },
  React.createElement(
    Modal,
    { title: 'Modal title', bsStyle: 'primary', backdrop: false, animation: false, container: mountNode, onRequestHide: handleHide },
    React.createElement(
      'div',
      { className: 'modal-body' },
      'One fine body...'
    ),
    React.createElement(
      'div',
      { className: 'modal-footer' },
      React.createElement(
        Button,
        null,
        'Close'
      ),
      React.createElement(
        Button,
        { bsStyle: 'primary' },
        'Save changes'
      )
    )
  )
);
```